# issue in change row in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a shopping Android app, I have a `CartActivity`. In my `CartActivity` I put `RecyclerView` and each row in this `RecyclerView` have 2 buttons, one (+) button to increase the quantity for this item in the cart and other (-) button to delete 1 from the quantity of this item in the row. 
Now when I have a single item in my cart, everything is ok. but when I have multi-item in cart (multi-row in RV) I have the issue which is: When I press (+) or (-) button on any item in `RecyclerView` the effect of quantity changing shown on the last item in this list (last row) and there is no changing on my selected row!

### this is my adapter code:

```
package com.example.souqsenae.adapters;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.souqsenae.API_Utility.IApi;
import com.example.souqsenae.API_Utility.RetrofitBuilder;
import com.example.souqsenae.R;
import com.example.souqsenae.activities.cartActivity;
import com.example.souqsenae.models.AddToCart;
import com.example.souqsenae.models.CartInfo;
import com.example.souqsenae.models.Parts;
import com.example.souqsenae.models.RemoveProduct;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class CartAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.CartAdapterViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<CartInfo.Item> mItem;
    private ItemOnClickHandler mItemOnClickHandler;
    RetrofitBuilder rB = new RetrofitBuilder();
    IApi service = rB.retrofit.create(IApi.class);
     int totalQty =0;   int subTotal = 0;
    TextView tv1, tv4;
    private static SharedPreferences pref;
    String cookie;


    public CartAdapter(ItemOnClickHandler cartAdapterOnClickHandler, Context _context) {
        mItemOnClickHandler = cartAdapterOnClickHandler;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences("log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public void setProductsData(ArrayList<CartInfo.Item> item) {
        mItem = item;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<CartInfo.Item> newList) {
        int lastIndex = getItemCount();
        mItem.addAll(newList);

        notifyItemRangeInserted(lastIndex, newList.size());
    }

    public void clear() {
        int size = mItem.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                mItem.remove(0);
            }

            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CartAdapter.CartAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_cart, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        CartAdapterViewHolder viewHolder = new CartAdapterViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CartAdapter.CartAdapterViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
       // viewHolder.iv.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_transition_animation));
        viewHolder.container.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.fade_transition_animation));


        final CartInfo.Item cartInfo = mItem.get(position);


        tv1 = viewHolder.qty;
        TextView tv2 = viewHolder.tvItemName;
        TextView tv3 = viewHolder.tvItemDesc;
        tv4 = viewHolder.tvSubTotal;

        Button button = viewHolder.btnMin;
        Button button1 = viewHolder.btnPlus;

        totalQty = cartInfo.getQty();
        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(totalQty));
        tv2.setText(cartInfo.getName());

        tv4.setText(String.valueOf(cartInfo.getSubtotal()));
        cookie = pref.getString("cookie", "");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if((totalQty -1) >0){
                    totalQty = totalQty -1;
                    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(totalQty));

                    subTotal = totalQty * (cartInfo.getPrice());
                    tv4.setText(String.valueOf(subTotal));

                }
                if((totalQty - 1) == 0){
                    // remove from cart:
                    String row = cartInfo.getRowid();
                    String product_id = cartInfo.getId();



                    Call<RemoveProduct> call = service.updateCartQty( cookie,product_id,totalQty);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<RemoveProduct>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<RemoveProduct> call, Response<RemoveProduct> response) {
                            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, cartActivity.class);
                                context.startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<RemoveProduct> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int vendor = Integer.parseInt(cartInfo.getVendor());
                int product_id = Integer.parseInt(cartInfo.getId());


                Call<AddToCart> call = service.addToCart(cookie,product_id,vendor,1);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<AddToCart>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AddToCart> call, Response<AddToCart> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful()){
                            totalQty = totalQty +1;
                            tv1.setText(String.valueOf(totalQty));
                            subTotal = totalQty * (cartInfo.getPrice());
                            tv4.setText(String.valueOf(subTotal));

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AddToCart> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });




            }
        });

    }

    // Returns the total count of items in the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mItem == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return mItem.size();
    }


    public class CartAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        public final Button btnPlus;
        public final Button btnMin;
        public final TextView qty;
        public final TextView tvItemName;
        public final TextView tvItemDesc;
        public final TextView tvSubTotal;
        public final LinearLayout container;



        public CartAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.partCount);
            tvItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            tvItemDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_description);
            tvSubTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTotal);
            btnMin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMin);
            btnPlus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
            container = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_part_item);


            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            CartInfo.Item selectedProduct = mItem.get(position);
            mItemOnClickHandler.onClickItem(selectedProduct);
        }
    }

    public interface ItemOnClickHandler {
        void onClickItem(CartInfo.Item cartInfo);

    }



}
```

I don't know what the wrong :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `interface` to perform click operations.

Whenever button clicked, update the quantity for a specific item and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to made change for quantity in your model when click + or - button. So you have to add `cartInfo.setQty(totalQty);` inside your button clicks

Don't use global variables if you are using variable inside onBind()

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if((totalQty -1) >0){
                    cartInfo.setQty(cartInfo.getQty() -1);
                    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(cartInfo.getQty()));
                    tv4.setText(String.valueOf(cartInfo.getQty() * (cartInfo.getPrice())));

                }
                if((totalQty - 1) == 0){
                    // remove from cart:
                    String row = cartInfo.getRowid();
                    String product_id = cartInfo.getId();
                    mItem.remove(cartInfo);


                    Call<RemoveProduct> call = service.updateCartQty( cookie,product_id,totalQty);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<RemoveProduct>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<RemoveProduct> call, Response<RemoveProduct> response) {
                            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, cartActivity.class);
                                context.startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<RemoveProduct> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int vendor = Integer.parseInt(cartInfo.getVendor());
                int product_id = Integer.parseInt(cartInfo.getId());
               cartInfo.setQty(cartInfo.getQty()+1);
              cartInfo.setQty(cartInfo.getQty()+1);
              tv1.setText(String.valueOf(cartInfo.getQty()));
              tv4.setText(String.valueOf(cartInfo.getQty() * (cartInfo.getPrice())));



                Call<AddToCart> call = service.addToCart(cookie,product_id,vendor,1);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<AddToCart>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AddToCart> call, Response<AddToCart> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful()){

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AddToCart> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });




            }
        });
```

Comment: thank u for answer, I change it like u said, but no thing changed